# Lists app in node- I get no errors but still not rendering . Item in the list should be moved into Done List on the same page but it's not happening

Tags: node.js, express, routes, ejs

I have a todo list app in node - using express and mongoose. What I am trying to do is add the items in a new list on the same page after they have been created. The items should have the option to be moved into another Done List. The list is created on the same page. When i click the Move to Done List btn nothing happens. The items are not rendered on the page in the Done List. I get no errors.  The folderList.ejs is this:

```
<ul>
  <% folderLists.forEach(folderList => { %>
  <li>
    <%= folderList.name %>
    <!-- Form to delete items from the list -->
    <form action="/folderLists/<%= folder._id %>/deleteItem/<%= folderList._id %>"  method="post" style="display: inline;">
        <button type="submit">Delete</button>
    </form>
    
    <!-- Form to move item to Done List -->
    <form action="/folderLists/<%= folder._id %>/moveToDone/<%= folderList._id %>" method="post" style="display: inline;">
        <button type="submit">Move to Done List</button>
    </form>
  </li>
<% }); %>
```

```
<h2>Done List</h2>
<ul>
 <% folderLists.forEach(folderList => { %>
     <% if (folderList.checked) { %>
         <li>
             <%= folderList.name %>
             <!-- Additional actions if needed -->
         </li>
     <% } %>
 <% }); %>
```

```
<a href="/mainFolder">Go back to Main Folders</a>.
```

The folderLists.js routes :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
// Import the Folder and Task models
const Folder = require('../models/folder');
const FolderList = require('../models/folderList');
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const folder = await Folder.findById(id);
    // Fetch all items for the given folder ID
    const allItems = await FolderList.find({ folder: id });
    console.log('allItems:', allItems);  
    const folderLists = allItems.filter(item => !item.checked);
    console.log('folderLists:', folderLists);
    res.render('folderLists', { folder, folderLists });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});
```

// Add item to the list

```
router.post('/:id/addItem', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { itemName } = req.body;
    await FolderList.create({ name: itemName, folder: id });
    res.redirect(`/folderLists/${id}`);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});
```

// Delete item from the list

```
router.post('/:id/deleteItem/:itemId', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { itemId } = req.params;
    await FolderList.findByIdAndDelete(itemId);
    res.redirect(`/folderLists/${req.params.id}`);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});
```

// Add item to the Done List

```
router.post('/:id/moveToDone/:itemId', async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const { itemId } = req.params;
      console.log('Item ID:', itemId);
      // Find the item by ID
      const folderList = await FolderList.findById(itemId);
      console.log('Folder List:', folderList);
      // Update the item to mark it as checked
      folderList.checked = true;
      await folderList.save();
      console.log('Item moved to Done List successfully.');  // Add this line
      res.redirect(`/folderLists/${req.params.id}`);
  } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error moving item to Done List:', err);
      res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});
module.exports = router;
```

This is the model for folderList.js :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const folderListSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  folder: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Folder', required: true },
});
const FolderList = mongoose.model('FolderList', folderListSchema);
module.exports = FolderList;
```

When i click the Move to Done List btn nothing happens. The items are not rendered on the page in the Done List. I get no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your folderListSchema to ensure your schema includes a checked field. Maybe that is why it is not working?

```js
const folderListSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  folder: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Folder', required: true },
  checked: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It definitely helped me identify the problem!! After modifying the schema i have modified the rendering logic to handle what i wanted in  route and in ejs and .....res.render('folderLists', { folder, checkedItems, uncheckedItems }); and it works!